# Build SQL Query in client or server side?

Tags: sql, client-server

I have doubts between two options:

1. Build the query in client side and send it to server.
2. Sending from client the needed knowledge in order to build the query in server side.

In which side I will prefer to build the query?

Advantages / Disadvantages?

Thanks.

Comment: using stored procedures will be better if you know what kind of query you are going to build and stored procedures perform better.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to prefer building queries on the server side and either storing them as Stored Procedures on the sql server or building the query string in a backend language like PHP.

Building the query in something like javascript and sending to the server, creates the possibility of deviants doing inline altering of your javascript and submitting the query string through something like firebug.  If you build the query string in a backend (server-side) language, the only thing the user would have access to alter would be input variables (if applicable).  Because of this, you should always check and cleanse all input variables for sql injection.

Removing as much access to raw code from the end user as possible seems to always be the best option, in terms of application security.  Someone else may weigh-in about performance limitations; but if a user alters and submits their own query string through a javascript console and drops your entire table, performance won't really be a factor anymore will it?